# Docker Compose (docker-compose) couldn't connect to docker daemon on Windows Server 2016 TP5

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2016, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am trying to get **docker-compose** to work on **Windows Server 2016 TP5**. I have installed **Docker Desktop for Windows** (not Docker Toolbox) as a service, which works perfectly. I have downloaded the latest docker-compose for windows from https://dl.bintray.com/docker-compose/master/ and put it in the same path as Docker (after unblocking the downloaded file, and renaming it to docker-compose.exe.

When I run the `docker-compose up` (in Powershell as an Administrator), I get the following error:

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to install
>   Docker:
>
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

Here are the *docker* and *docker-compose* information on my machine:

Docker:

```
Client:
Version:      1.12.1
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   23cf638
Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.12.1
API version:  1.24
Go version:   go1.6.3
Git commit:   23cf638
Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Docker Compose:

```
docker-compose version 1.9.0dev, build f65f89a
```

Comment: I also tried installing _docker-compose_ using __chocolatey__. It installs `docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 004ddae`. That didn't work either, and running `docker-compose up` shows exactly the same error.

Comment: Just restart docker, this solve this problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to set your `DOCKER_HOST`:

```
$ENV:DOCKER_HOST="npipe://\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
```

Alternatively, when registering the engine, you can make it listen on TCP too:

```
dockerd.exe -H npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine -H localhost:2375 --register-service
```

There are more details on this [Compose issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3901)

Comment: Thanks @friism. I found your article earlier:
https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/
and I did the exact same thing as you have explain both in the article and here, except I unregistered the service first. It worked. However, I am getting another issue, which is related to networking. I realized that it is still an open issue with docker-compose on Windows: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3252

Comment: @moriazat that's because you're using TP5. On RTM (and with all the latest Windows Updates), docker-compose works fully for a single host. Download free RTM eval here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016